# Is there any possibility to recover truncated MariaDB data without bin logs?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I accidentally truncated a database yesterday. I tried with binlog and it shows the following error:

> ERROR 1381 (HY000): You are not using binary logging

Is there ANY ANY possibility that I can get that data back?
By using any disk utilities or Anything else? I am ready to put in any amount of time and efforts.

Comment: No backups? Yowch.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TRANSACTIONS in your code, TRUNCATE can be rolled back. If there is no transaction used and TRUNCATE operation is committed, it can not be retrieved from log file. TRUNCATE is DDL operation and it is not logged in log file.

[source](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/03/04/sql-server-rollback-truncate-command-in-transaction/)

Comment: The link is for SQL Server. It may still have the same core message, but ideally answers should be specific to the DBMSes the OP tagged.